# The sql query does not pass the arguments

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing an android application and I need to search the data base, this is the method I use:

```
public Cursor getData(String table, String keyword, SQLiteDatabase db){

    String selection;
    Cursor cursor;

    switch (table){
        case "User":
            String [] projection = {id,name,phone};
            selection = "username LIKE ?";
            String [] selection_arg = {keyword};
            cursor = db.query("User",projection,selection,selection_arg,null,null,null);
            break;
        //omitted
        default:
            return null;
    }
    return cursor;
```

The user put in the keyword

```
keyword = search_user.getText().toString();
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getData(ShippingApplication.User.USER_TABLE,keyword,db);
```

The code does not work, when I debug, I see the mQuery of the db variable is:
`SQLiteQuery: SELECT userID, userName, phoneNumber FROM User WHERE userName LIKE ?`
It looks like the query does not pass the value of the keyword in to the sql command.
Could someone tell me what's wrong?

EDIT 2: I change the code a little bit and now it works:

```
String selection = ShippingApplication.User.name + " LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'";
Cursor cursor = db.query(The table name,projection,selection,null,null,null,null);
```

Comment: @KrishnaV there, I added my log cat

Comment: place related logcat only

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to android, I don't really know which one is related, maybe there's nothing related in there, idk

Comment: post SQLiteQuery: SELECT userID... logcat, you posted non-related db log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this way**

**please check your SQLiteDatabase object is not null**

**after that check Table is created or not**

**i get the cursor count i already debug it and it's working fine for me**

```
public Cursor getData(String table, String keyword, SQLiteDatabase db){

        String selection;
        Cursor cursor;

        switch (table){
            case "Tbl_staticContent":
                String [] projection = {"PageTitle","Content"};
                selection = "PageTitle LIKE ?";
                String [] selection_arg = {keyword};
                cursor = db.query("Tbl_staticContent",projection,selection,selection_arg,null,null,null);

                Log.e("count",""+cursor.getCount());
                //I have create table and stored data and also check the like condtion also it's work fine and get the cursor.getCount() > 0 also .

                break;

            default:
                return null;
        }
        return cursor;
}
```

Comment: the table is already created, the SQLiteDatabase object points to the correct database; somehow the method db.query does not pass the value of selection_arg to the question point, I have no idea why, I change something and now it works, see my edit2, do you know why it works now? I'm confused

Comment: good...this way also posible. db.query u direct pass select * from your table name and like statement also.